# Neo4j Java OGM select with lock

Tags: java, neo4j, locking, neo4j-ogm

I am trying to select a path with locking the last node in that path using Java OGM for Neo4j.

To do that in cypher I have written the following query:

```
String q = "Match path = (p:Root) - [*1..100]-(m:Leaf) WHERE m.State = 'Non-Processed' WITH m,p,path ORDER BY length(path) Limit 1 SET m.State = 'Processing' RETURN path"
```

It selects the necessary path with locking the last leaf(by changing its `State` property).

However, when I try to execute this query:

```
session.query(Path.class, q, propertyMap)
```

I get a `java.lang.RuntimeException: query() only allows read only cypher. To make modifications use execute()`

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: did you try `execute` method instead of `session.query()`?

Comment: `Method threw 'java.lang.RuntimeException' exception.:  execute() must not return data. Use query() instead.`

Comment: then do not return anything from the query, remove `RETURN path`

Comment: There are multiple threads performing the same query and processing paths. In order to avoid multiple therads to process the same path I am trying to implement this mechanism of locking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using an older version of neo4j-ogm which had the restriction on session.query(). Please upgrade to neo4j-ogm 1.1.4

Answer (score 0):

Found a (probably not the best) solution.

```
String uid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
String lockQuery = "Match path = (p:Root) - [*1..100]-(m:Leaf)"
   + "WHERE m.State = 'Non-Processed' "
   + "WITH m,p,path ORDER BY length(path) Limit 1 SET m.lock = " + uid
session.execute(lockQuery);
String getQuery = "Match path = (p:Root) - [*1..100]-(m:Leaf)"
   + "WHERE m.lock = " + uid + "RETURN path";
Path path = session.query(Path.class, getQuery, new Hashmap<String, Object>());
```

Will this work?